# when creating an instance of an object with object type with a reference variable , which methods are available to call?

Tags: java

so if I have a class A, and I also have a class B, and I create an object of class A such as

A refvariable = new B();

which methods will refvariable will have access to? the ones from class A or the methods from class B? or both?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13077989/7975771

Answer (score 0):

The only way that code will compile and run is if B is a subclass of A.  If it is, then you will only have access to the methods defined in A, but you may end up running code that is defined in B if B has overloaded methods or variables defined in A with its own versions.

There are details that make things a bit more complicated, like if particular methods or variables are public or protected, and if you're calling the class from code in the same package, but I think that first paragraph gives you the basics of what you're asking about.  What's definitely true is that you can't use anything in B that you can't see defined in A.